# How can I dodge 200 lightning bolts in a row?

Tags: final-fantasy-10

In order to get the Sigil for Lulu's weapon, you need to dodge 200 lightning bolts.  In a row.  Without leaving the area.  It's a rather strenuous exercise, as lightning bolts are random, and require lightning-fast reflexes to dodge.  Even then, missing a single one is cause for rage, because now you have to start all over.  Is there an easier way to do this that doesn't involve just waiting and hoping?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is, in fact, an easier way to do this!  There is a specific area you can go to in the Thunder Plains, and cause the lightning bolts to hit the same spot, over and over.  This makes it *much* more consistent to dodge, since the timing is no longer random and much easier to predict.

The area is just outside of Guadosalam. If you've activated three of the Cactuar statues, the little ghost is running around just south of it.  It looks like a little hollow, right by a tower.  The trick is to walk just over the dip in the ground, and that's when lightning will strike.  Press X as you move into the dip, and you will dodge it.  The timing is pretty generous, I've found; you can move into the hollow, and press X before the flash, and you'll still dodge it.  Then it's just run to the tower, loop around, and go at it again.

Doing it this way gives you one lightning bolt about every three or four seconds, which means it'll take around ten to fifteen minutes to amass the necessary 200.  Note that you won't have any indicator that lets you know when you hit 200; you have to go to the Travel Agency and read the book to see how many you dodged in a row.  But don't go there until you miss, because leaving the area will reset your count.

To see this in action:

Comment: How come there are no random encounters? I keep having to fight between lightnings!!!

Comment: @Chu You'll need to equip something that turns off encounters while you do this.

Comment: @Chu It's best to save this for after you get the airship and are working on your capture quests. If you've taken care of your captures in the cavern of the stolen faith, then you fought a lot of ghosts. By the time that I had finished capturing all my Tonberrys I had gotten 4 no encounter armor from all the ghosts I had fought.

Answer (score 7):

[Frank's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/162028/53654) is the correct one. But I wanted to add some points that helped me:

1. As I said in [this comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162027/how-can-i-dodge-200-lightning-bolts-in-a-row#comment289210_162028) you'll wanna do this after completing your captures in the [Cavern of the Stolen Fayth](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Cavern_of_the_Stolen_Fayth). That way you will have fought enough [Ghosts](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Ghost_%28Final_Fantasy_X%29) to obtain No Encounter armor for one of your party members. The armor should be equipped before attempting this side-quest as lightning can strike immediately after a battle.
2. There is [some advice out there](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/197344-final-fantasy-x/55477395#5) recommending dodging lightning in the crevice with the Cactuar Stone.[image: Crevice] This is where I accomplished this side-quest in the American Version of Final Fantasy X. The International version tweaks the timing though, making it nearly impossible to dodge lightning in said crevice. So stick to the crater location in [Frank's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/162028/53654).
3. The distance you run from the crater determines how long it will take you to complete the side-quest so don't run all the way to the tower each time You only need to go about half way there. [image: Half way between the tower and crater]
4. Trying to reach 200 with out taking breaks can be grueling and will wear down your concentration. I reached 200 the first time I decided to take breaks every 20 dodges (without taking breaks I was averaging about 60.) You can take a break by pausing or just standing under the tower. **Do not** take a break by just standing half way to the tower. Lightning can still strike there randomly if it hasn't been forced to strike by running to the crater recently.
5. Lastly, you *do not* get the [Lightning Dancer Trophy](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_X_HD_Remaster_Trophies#Lightning_Dancer) until you actually obtain the [Venus Sigil](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_X_Items#Venus_Sigil) in the Thunder Plains Travel Agency, so you *must* keep count for yourself, don't expect an achievement notification to let you know you're done.

http://www.psnprofiles.com lists the [Lightning Dancer Trophy](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_X_HD_Remaster_Trophies#Lightning_Dancer) as more rare than even the [Chocobo Rider Trophy](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_X_HD_Remaster_Trophies#Chocobo_Rider), which seems astounding to me. (Of course they also list it as more rare than the [Weapon Master Trophy](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_X_HD_Remaster_Trophies#Weapon_Master), so maybe take those numbers with a grain of salt.) Either way this can be a difficult quest and I hope my tips have helped you. Good luck!

Comment: Taking breaks every 20 worked for me on the first time too, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score -3):

if you just tap x square x square back and forth at a decent pace itll keep dodging them